# How does IE8 handle this tag <meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=9” />

Tags: internet-explorer-8, x-ua-compatible

I know  `<meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=9” />` will force IE9 to display a page in IE9 standard way. What I want to know is  How does IE8 handle this tag  ?

Render the page in a IE 8 standard mode or compatible mode? (Could not find any XP with IE8 around)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a webpage specifies a document compatibility mode that is not
>   supported by the version of Internet Explorer used to view the
>   webpage, the webpage will be displayed in the highest document mode
>   supported by that version of Internet Explorer. For example, a page
>   that specifies IE9 mode will be displayed in IE8 mode when viewed by
>   Internet Explorer 8. Earlier versions of the browser will use the
>    directive, if any, to determine how to display the webpage.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx#Content